# why is my module dir so big?

Tags: kernel

so when I make a custom built kernel, the modules folder is way bigger than the shipped one any idea why?

```
joel@joel-UX31E:~$ du --max-depth=1 -h /lib/modules/

140M    /lib/modules/3.2.6-030206-generic
2.0G    /lib/modules/3.2.6-test

joel@joel-UX31E:~$ diff linux/linux-3.2.6/.config /boot/config-3.2.6-030206-generic
3c3
< # Linux/x86_64 3.2.6 Kernel Configuration
---
> # Linux/x86_64 3.2.6-030206-generic Kernel Configuration
65c65
< CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-test"
---
> CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely that your kernel modules include debug information.  If you set the `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP` environment variable to `1` when installing the modules, the debugging information will be removed.

Comment: awesome, where did you find that information, i did a quick grep through `make help` output and I didn't find anything

Comment: You can find information about the various environment variables that affect the build process in the kernel documentation: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt